# Get one thing from a line and concatenate it with one thing from another line

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, perl

I have the following:

```
2018-11-10 23:57:21 [COMMAND]: sar -u 10 5

AIX host 1 7    11/10/18

System configuration: lcpu=64  mode=Capped

23:57:21    %usr    %sys    %wio   %idle   physc
23:57:31      10       7       0      83   16.00
23:57:41       9       6       0      85   16.00
23:57:51       9       6       0      85   16.00
23:58:01       9       7       0      84   16.00
23:58:11      10       6       0      84   16.00

Average        9       6       0      84   16.00

2018-11-10 23:58:21 [COMMAND]: sar -u 10 5

AIX host 1 7    11/10/18

System configuration: lcpu=64  mode=Capped

23:58:21    %usr    %sys    %wio   %idle   physc
23:58:31      10       8       0      82   15.99
23:58:41       9       6       0      85   16.00
23:58:51       9       6       0      85   16.00
23:59:01       9       6       0      84   16.00
23:59:11      10       6       0      83   16.00

Average       10       6       0      84   16.00
```

I need to get the time with the average value of `%idle`:

```
2018-11-10 23:57:21|84
2018-11-10 23:58:21|84
```

Comment: actually i am getting this file from another server and it is only one file

Comment: This is using this site as a script-writing service.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Going by your input file as-is, a simple `awk` command as simple as below should suffice.

```
awk '/sar/{ time=$1" "$2; next }/Average/{ print time"|"$5 }' file
```

Answer (score 5):

A couple of choices:

- `awk`

  ```
  $ awk '/COMMAND/{printf "%s %s", $1,$2}/Average/{print "|"$5}' file 
  2018-11-10 23:57:21|84
  2018-11-10 23:58:21|84
  ```
- `perl`

  ```
  $ perl -ale '$k="$F[0] $F[1]" if /COMMAND/; print "$k|$F[4]" if /Average/' file 
  2018-11-10 23:57:21|84
  2018-11-10 23:58:21|84
  ```

Answer (score 2):

This Perl one-liner should do the trick:

```
perl -lne'$d=$1 if /^(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s+\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})/;
if(/^Average\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+\S+\s+(\S+)/) {print "$d|$1";}'
```

(I made it two lines, so it's more readable.) You need to feed it with input though. The file name at the end, or `<file_name` at the beginning or the end, or a pipe will do. The workings are these:

1. Go to a line with date and time at the beginning and memorise it.
2. Go to a line with `Average` at beginning and once there, print the memorised date and time plus the `|` sign and the average taken from the fifth column assuming whitespace column separation.
3. Point 1. repeats.